# How to Combine two models into a single model and pass it to view using asp.net MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, model

I'm trying to combine two models (tblCategories and tblProducts) into a single model and pass it to a view. But was not able to.

**tblCategory.cs** which is main model has the following data

```
namespace ScaffoldCreate.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblCategory
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**tblProduct.cs**

```
public partial class tblProduct
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductName { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public string StockStatus { get; set; } 
        public IList<tblCategory> CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to get tblCategory into tblProduct and tried to retrieve that in index page as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubCategoryId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StockStatus)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

But, I was not able to get through it. Could any assist me in solving this ?

Comment: what is chandu in **item.chandu.CategoryName** ?

Comment: Hey, sorry that was a typo! I updated the latest code. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure but i think you've probably need to create another flatten viewmodel which contains all the attributes from both model you mentioned

Answer (score 7):

Use the ViewModel for your View that will Solve your Problem::

```
class CommonViewModel 
{

   Model1 model1;
   Model2 model2;
}
```

where Model1 & Model2 are your Models aS::

```
public class Model1 
{
  public int ID{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and Model2 like::

```
public class Model2 
{
  public int ID{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

And into your View you do it as strongly Typed::

```
@model ProjectName.CommonViewModel
```

Here you can use the Model1 as::
you can pass the Model to Another Partial View As well and can use in the same view as well::

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialViewName",Model.Model1)

@foreach (var item in Model.Model2)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubCategoryId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StockStatus)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Rahul, It would be great if you can add view code on how to access multiple modals with razor code.

Comment: @Chandana If it is helpfull then you should rate the answer

Comment: @Rahul can I ask you what should be in controller, Edit please if it's possible. really thank you