# Getting data from two tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 tables **tbl_computer** and **tbl_computerperipheral**
I need a  editor view which consists of data from both tables.

How Can I get 2 tables  in a single view so that I can insert data into 2 tables at once.

Thanx

Comment: are you getting data from two table, and populate in single view? yes or no

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I don't think that your question is very clear. Please describe your problem in full with as much detail as possible. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult Edit(CompPeripheral cp, int c_id,int em_id,int asset_id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            cp.Compconfig.c_id = c_id;
            cp.Compconfig.em_id = em_id;
            cp.Compconfig.asset_id = asset_id;
            db.tbl_compconfig.Add(cp.Compconfig);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var id = db.tbl_compconfig.Max(a => a.comp_id);
            cp.Comperipheral.comp_id = id;
            //saving Comp Peripheral in database
            db.tbl_comperipheral.Add(cp.Comperipheral);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.asset_id = new SelectList(db.tbl_assetm, "asset_id", "asset_name", cp.Compconfig.asset_id);
        ViewBag.em_id = new SelectList(db.tbl_employee, "em_id", "em_fullname", cp.Compconfig.em_id);
        ViewBag.c_id = new SelectList(db.tbl_client, "c_id", "c_name", cp.Compconfig.c_id);
        return View(cp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Better Reference just have a look to ::

[How to Combine two models into a single model and pass it to view using asp.net MVC razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368726/how-to-combine-two-models-into-a-single-model-and-pass-it-to-view-using-asp-net/22369721#22369721)

and then on Form submit on server side (i.e. into controller's action) save the data coming from view in the form like::

```
public ActionResult Save(CommonViewModel common)
    {
        var FirstModel = new FirstModel();
        FirstModel = common.FirstModel;
        db.Entry(FirstModel).State = EntityState.Added;

        var SecondModel = new SecondModel();
        SecondModel = common.SecondModel;
        db.Entry(SecondModel).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

May be this answer will be helpful to get answer of your Query.

Comment: Thanx for the reply Rahul RJ .. When  I use the above code I cannot get data. The code FirstModel = common.FirstModel doesnot give all the data. I need to Add all fields one by one. Is there any other way